# Webpack 2 / TypeScript 2 Upgrade to Angular 1 TypeScript 1.8 App - Views Do Not Display Properly

Tags: angularjs, typescript, webpack

I've been working successfully with an Angular 1 app built on TypeScript 1.8 with Material Design. I was using Webpack 1 to handle the build process.

Everything was working fine but I am attempting to upgrade to Webpack 2.2.1 and TypeScript 2.2.1. Now, when I build the app the views do not display properly and seem to be missing the angular-material support for the elements.

There are absolutely no errors generated during the Webpack build and no browser console errors. I have no idea how to diagnose at this point.

I have recreated the problem with a streamlined app that shows the login page view (I disconnected any controller / service functionality) at https://github.com/focher/myapp.git

Would appreciate any tips or advice how to troubleshoot and resolve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my own answer to the problem. In the `config/webpack.common.config.js` file, I switched the `'to-string-loader'` to `'style-loader'`. Then I issued a `npm install --save-dev style-loader`. After that, my app built and displays fine.

Previous
`{
          test: /\.css$/,
          use: [
            'to-string-loader',
            'css-loader'
          ]
        },`

`{
          test: /\.css$/,
          use: [
            'style-loader',
            'css-loader'
          ]
        },`